# Websockets with Node JS, Express, Heroku: Adding routes breaks web socket connection

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

First time SO post!

I am a jode js newbie and looking for some help while I am following the the Heroku tutorial here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-websockets (option 1)

I am creating an app that will use web sockets with node.js, Heroku, and express. When I run the server.js code straight as it is from the example above it works.  Now I am trying to add routes and it breaks the web socket connection for some reason.

server.js:

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const SocketServer = require('ws').Server;
const path = require('path');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const INDEX = path.join(__dirname, 'index.html');

const server = express()

const ADMIN= path.join(__dirname, +'/admin/' + 'adminPage.html');

const wss = new SocketServer({ server });


  var router = express.Router();

 var app=express();
    // home page route
    router.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.sendFile(INDEX);
    });
    // admin page route
    router.get('/admin', function(req, res) {
        res.sendFile(ADMIN);
    });
    // apply the routes to our application
    app.use(express.static('public'))
    app.use('/', router);

    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${ PORT }`));

    wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
      console.log('Client connected');
      ws.on('close', () => console.log('Client disconnected'));
    });

setInterval(() => {
    wss.clients.forEach((client) => {
      client.send(new Date().toTimeString());
    });
  }, 1000);
```

Current Index.html:

```
  <p id='server-time'></p>
    <script>
      var HOST = location.origin.replace(/^http/, 'ws')
      var ws = new WebSocket(HOST);
      var el = document.getElementById('server-time');
      ws.onmessage = function (event) {
        el.innerHTML = 'Server time: ' + event.data;
      };
    </script>
```

The redirect to the admin page works, but the index.html page returns the following error:

```
**WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200**
```

I am sure this is a simple mistake but I just can't find it - appreciate anyones help!

Answer (score 0):

You are creating two instances of `express`: `app` and `server`. You use the first for the router and set it to listen, and the second for websockets. You’re not setting the second to listen to anything so no websocket connections can be made. I assume you meant to use `server` for everything so remove `app` and connect the router etc to `server`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help Sami! I tried to remove app as you suggested but it still did not work. I found another online resource and this is the final working code:

```
const SocketServer = require('ws').Server;
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
//init Express
var app = express();
//init Express Router
var router = express.Router();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var admin = path.join(__dirname, '/admin/adminPage.html');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});
app.get('/admin', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(admin);
});
var server = app.listen(port, function () {
    //listening
})
const wss = new SocketServer({ server });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
    console.log("connection ...");
});
setInterval(() => {
    wss.clients.forEach((client) => {
      client.send(new Date().toTimeString());
    });
  }, 1000);
```